# Is it possible to create a Google Merchant Center test account?

Tags: google-ads-api, google-shopping-api

I need to create a new shopping campaign by using the Google AdWords API. But before that, I wanted to check the end to end flow for shopping campaign with Google Ads and Google Merchant Center UI.
I've completed the following steps:

- Created Google Ads Manager and Client account
- Created Google merchant center account and linked the above account with it.
- Using the content APIs, I uploaded some products to the merchant center

But while creating a shopping campaign from my client account, I'm not able to proceed beyond step 1 i.e providing campaign settings.
Currently, I've not provided any campaign URL as I don't have any website to point to. I am also not sure about how to add the template URL and suffix. Would be great if someone can guide me on this.

Could you please let me know if there is any way to use the existing Google merchant center account as a test account where I don't need to provide the campaign URL?